# Присвоить переменной данные JSON файла

Tags: javascript, json

Доброго времени суток. Имею json файл(иллюзия ответа от сервера)

```
{  "executors":[ {
        "executorID": "1",
        "executorName": "Бородин Алексей Иванович",
        "tasks": [
                {   
                "taskID": "1",
                "taskNumber": "ATGSM-7355",
                "taskTitle": "Использование переменных в настройках SEO (часть 1)"
                },
                {
                "taskID": "2",
                "taskNumber": "ATGSM-7355",
                "taskTitle": "Использование переменных в настройках SEO (часть 1)"
                },
                {
                "taskID": "33",
                "taskNumber": "ATGSM-7355",
                "taskTitle": "Использование переменных в настройках SEO (часть 1)"
                 }
                 ],
        "executorID": "21",
        "executorName": "Иван Иванович",
        "tasks": [{
                "taskID": "34",
                "taskNumber": "ATGSM-7355",
                "taskTitle": "Использование переменных в настройках SEO (часть 1)"
                },
                {
                "taskID": "36",
                "taskNumber": "ATGSM-7355",
                "taskTitle": "Использование переменных в настройках SEO (часть 1)"
                 }
                 ] 
}]

}
```

Пытаюсь этот файл запросить и присвоить переменной что бы потом использовать в шаблонизаторе.

```
var data = $.getJSON('ajax/example.json');
```

Проблема в том что в переменной будет находится объект с кучей всего лишнего. А как из него вытянуть конкретно данные увы способ найти не могу.

Требуется именно вытянуть данные что бы потом разобрать их. Варианты обработать в `callback` функции не подходят.

В конечном итоге этот файл будет разбираться в структуру:

```
Исполнитель_1 (его св-ва) 
  Задание1  Задание2 
Исполнитель_2 (его св-ва) 
 Задание1  Задание2
```

И тд.

Заранее спасибо большое!

ЗЫ. Если есть какая то возможность реализовать требуемую структуру в самой колбек функции дайте знать в каком направлении это развить, фантазии не хватает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.getJSON` возвращает не запрошенные данные, a объект `jqXHR` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/, который Вам здесь вообще не нужен.

```
var data = null;
$.getJSON('ajax/example.json', function(result) {
  data = result;
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Долго бился с этим. Подскажите почему фаер фокс ругается    `Ошибка синтаксического анализа XML: некорректно
Адрес: file:///E:/Site/SportM/public_html/json/data.json
Строка 1, символ 1:`

Comment: @Вячеслав На тот JSON, который у Вас в вопросе, - не ругается.

Comment: @Вячеслав У Вас в этом файле что-нибудь есть перед первой открывающей `{`?

Comment: И на тот файл который в вопросе тоже ругается. Нет первый символ открывающая скобка. Подскажите откуда вы взяли переменную "result" где почитать полный функционал. Спасибо вам огромное. * где тут лайк посавить*

Comment: @Вячеслав Так, по порядку. Если мой ответ подходит к Вашему вопросу, Вы можете отметить ответ как принятый, щелкнув по знаку "галочка" слева. Когда Ваша репутацию достигнет необходимого уровня (кажется, 15) Вы также сможете голосовать за (и против) вопросы/ответы, щелкая по стрелкам вверх/вниз слева от них.

Comment: @Вячеслав Про переменную `result`. Это всего лишь название формального параметра Вашей (нашей) функции обработчика события `success`. Вы можете назвать этот параметр как угодно, главное, чтобы его название не конфликтовало с другими переменными.

Comment: @Вячеслав Прочитать, в первую очередь, следует описание функции `$.getJSON` - по ссылке в ответе. Другие браузеры грузят данные без ошибок?

Comment: Хром вообще отказывает нормально воспринимать локальные файлы и не подгружает данные.  `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.` Поэтому все тесты делаю в фаерфоксе.